# Remove dynamically created row in table in js

Tags: javascript, function, html-table

I am using Otree live methods to implement a game with two roles: sellers send offers, which buyers can accept. I implemented this with a container and a container that adds clickable table rows:

```
<div class="container">
<h2> Job offers </h2>
<table class="table">
    <tbody id="offers_table">
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

function liveRecv(data) {
    let current_offer = data["offer"];
    let player_offer = data["from"];
    let requested_effort = data["effort"];
    document.getElementById("offers_table").innerHTML +=
        `<tr><td> 
            Player ${player_offer} offered ${current_offer} for ${requested_effort} effort
            <button class="button" onclick="acceptOffer()"> Accept </button>          
        </td></tr>`;
}
```

Now I need to define the `acceptOffer()` function which should remove the row from the table which the person clicked (there are other players). In principle I can use similar code as above with `-=` but how can I reference the newly created element?

Comment: Use `acceptOffer(this)`. Then the function can use DOM traversal functions to find the containing row and remove it.

Comment: Will it then only remove the button? I want it to remove the whole row including the text. I thought I should reference to the <tr> element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass "this" - a pointer to the button, as a parameter to the acceptOffer()  function

```
 <button class="button" onclick="acceptOffer(this)"> Accept </button>
```

Further, in the function itself, through the method .parentNode go to the row and remove it

```
function acceptOffer(el) {
  const offer = document.querySelector("#offers_table");
  offer.removeChild(el.parentNode.parentNode);
  return false;
}
```

or else you can do this

```
function acceptOffer(el) {
  el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(el.parentNode.parentNode);
  return false;
}
```

PS:
the first one .parentNode is a cell.
the second .parentNode is a row. And third .parentNode is respectively tbody

Comment: There's now a `.remove()` method so you don't need to go up to the parent and use `removeChild()`.

Comment: Barmar, I know about this method, but try to use it in this context and get an error.

Comment: What error do you get? I can't think of a context where `parent.removeChild(child)` would work but `child.remove()` would fail.

Comment: this context is
    onclick="acceptOffer(this)"
just reproduce the author's example and solve it as child.remove()

Comment: And `el.parentNode.parentNode.remove()` gets an error? What error?

Comment: hmm.... it's very strange, but I remember exactly that there was an error, so I decided to do just that. Now this error is not reproduced, so I can not say what kind of error it was. Perhaps I had an older version of the browser. In any case, now it works, I take my words back.